# TV 50″ - PS4/movies (~$800)

Tags: gaming, hdtv

I'm looking for the best TV (in this price) which I will use for playing on PlayStation 4 and watching movies.

**Most important features:**

- Price: **~$800**
- Screen size: **~50"**
- Resolution: **FHD** (4K to expensive ?)
- **Wi-Fi**
- SmartTV: **Yes** (it can be any WebOS, Android, etc. but it has to run my DLNA server which is Mezzmo)
- Refresh rate: **good for gaming and movies** (120 Hz should be enough ?)
- Input lag: **good for gaming and movies** (40-50 ms will it be ok ?)
- VESA mount: **Yes**

**Additional data:**

- Room size: **25 square meters**
- Distance from TV: **2.5 meters**
- Room light: **really sunny room**
- Watching direction: **mostly from the front**, occasionally 45 degrees when I will invite guests

**Not important:**

- 3D

**My ideas:**

- [Sony KDL-50W755C](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/KDL-50W755C) - [specification](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/content/cnt-specs/KDL-50W755C/list) - ~$780 (in my country)
- [LG-50LF652V](http://www.lg.com/uk/tvs/lg-50LF652V) - $660 (in my country)
- [Philips 50PFH6550/88](http://icecat.us/us/p/philips/50pfh6550-88/led-tvs-8718863002049-50PFH6550-27120931.html) - $780 (in my country)

Comment: From your three ideas, I would go with the Sony. Generally speaking, Sony will be best for gaming and Sports. I do not know where you are from, but I would suggest that you take a look at Sonys 8series e.g W807, W809. I work with selling televisions on the weekends, (to afford university). And that is what I would recommend If you came in to my store. We dont sell philips, but the LG we have in the store, and that will not be as good as Sony. And done be fooled by an argument "Its 4k" because 4k is not that good/developed yet.

Comment: @Olba12 Both 50W807C and 50W809C are avaliable in my country for ~$850. Maybe if you will post one of them as an answer with wider description it will be valuable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sony w807C

Price: can only speak from where I live, but it seems from your comment that it is alittle over budget.

Screen size: 43, 50, 55

Resolution: full hd

wifi: yes

SmartTv: Yes, android, nuff said?

Refresh rate: 100Hz with 800Hz motionflow

Response time: 10-15 ms (Do not have any source on this, but this is stated from Sony who visited our store.)

VESA mount: Yes

3D: yes, active, no glasses included.

I would not recommend 4k, because 4k is useless without HDR, and there is no HDR standard today, which means that if the state a standard, and you television do not support the standard, again it will be useless. So even I you buy a 4k tv with HDR you might not be able get the full experience with 4k.

From what I have learned Sony has the best response time 10-15 ms on their flagships, LG around 30 ms and Samsung 45-50 ms. Please see if you can find a source on this. The Sony w807c has Sonys "finest" display, the  Triluminos display. This means that it will show a good picture when viewing from the angels, please see link provided.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-Sonys-Triluminos-technology

> DLNA server which is Mezzmo

I am unsure of this, but it runs android smart tv so if anyone should support it, I would be android.

Since it is android smart tv you can use the ps4 control to play games from google play, and aswell control the tv with it.

THe tv has a built in google cast, which means that you can cast you smartphone directly to the tv.

Comment: I wil buy SONY KDL-50W807C it costs $850 but I decided that it's worth going $50 over the budget and choosed this model.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered **Vizio** TV's? I am not sure if they are available in your country but they would fulfill all your requirements and you might even come in under your budget!

You could most **definitely** get a **50" FHD** (or 1080p) Vizio television for ~$800, but you *may* also be able to get an **M-Series Vizio**, this being their **4K model**, for around $800.

Vizio has **Wi-Fi** and is **DLNA** compatible.

The **refresh rate** is **120Hz** which is the recommended minimum for Gaming, Sports etc...

The **input lag** is **great** with Vizio as they offer a **Gaming mode** which reduces input lag.

It is also **VESA** mountable.

Although the television isn't **3D**, it does have  a **Full-Array backlight** with **local-dimming**. This translates to brighter colors and darker blacks with less light bleeding through in darker areas.

I worked at a Best Buy very recently and these are my TV's of choice as far as budget, quality, and feature set are concerned. Definitely worth a look!

Comment: Is [this](http://www.vizio.com/tvs/mseries/m50d1.html) the 4K you were talking about?

Comment: The link didn't work for me but it likely a regional thing. But just based on the URL yes that is absolutely the TV I am referring to.

Comment: @Steviet This TVs have really nice reviews and good price but unfortunately they are not avaliable in my country...

Comment: Ahhh, i'm sorry to hear that. I am partial to Sonys though, and the one you have listed seems to hit all your requirements. I can't find the native refresh rate anywhere of that model, but generally if the "MotionFlow" technology is above 120, then you've got a 120Hz native panel (its at 800 for the model you listed)